# How should I approach this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to work out the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\left\vert\frac{1}{1 + \alpha\,\iota}\,
\exp\left(-\,\frac{\pi x^{2}}
{\,\sqrt{\,{1 + \alpha\,\iota}\,}\,}\right)
\,\right\vert\mathrm{d}x
$$
Edit: $\alpha$ is just some constant and $\iota$ is supposed to be the imaginary unit. I was thinking that I can take the absolute of $\frac{1}{1+\alpha\iota}$ and throw that outside the integral. Then for ${\,\sqrt{\,{1 + \alpha\,\iota}\,}\,}$ I could find the square root, find the reciprocal and exploit $\left|e^{c\iota}=1\right|$ for any constant c and the fact that what remains looks like the pdf of a standard normal? Does that sound reasonable?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? What is $\iota$? Are they just constants? What have you tried?

Comment: @robjohn Sure! If they show a bit of interest, I'll add details...

Comment: Sorry, I was away for from the laptop for a bit. $\alpha$ is just some constant and $\iota$ is supposed to be the imaginary unit. I was thinking that I can take the absolute of the fraction and throw that outside, then for $\sqrt{1+\alpha\iota}$ I could find the square root, find the reciprocal and exploit $\left|(e^{c\iota}\right|$ and the fact that what remains looks like the pdf of a standard normal? Does that sound reasonable?

P.S. Sorry if using $\iota$ caused any confusion.

Comment: @Anonymous: add that to your question. It will make for good [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Comment: @robjohn Sure, thanks.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. What do you get when you do what you suggest?

Comment: Hint: $$ \frac1{\sqrt{1+\alpha i}}=\sqrt{\tfrac{1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}{2\left(1+\alpha^2\right)}}-i\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha)\sqrt{\tfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}{2\left(1+\alpha^2\right)}} $$

Answer (score 2):

As a hint:

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+ a I}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$

and
$$\left|\exp\left(-\pi \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+ a I}}\right)\right|  = \exp\left(-\pi x^2 Re\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + a I}}\right)\right),$$
where
$$Re\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + a I}}\right) = \frac{\cos(\arctan(a)/2)}{(1 + a^2)^{1/4}}.$$

Now the integral can be solved as a usual squared exponential integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the square root which preserves the quadrant; i.e.
$$
\sqrt{1+\alpha i}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}2}+i\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha)\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}2}
$$
Then, define $\beta$ as the real part of the reciprocal:
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1+\alpha i}}=\underbrace{\sqrt{\tfrac{1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}{2\left(1+\alpha^2\right)}}}_\beta-i\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha)\sqrt{\tfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}{2\left(1+\alpha^2\right)}}
$$
Furthermore, note that $\left|e^{x+iy}\right|=e^x$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|\frac1{1+\alpha i}\exp\left(-\frac{\pi x^2}{\sqrt{1+\alpha i}}\right)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\pi\beta x^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{\beta\left(1+\alpha^2\right)}}\\
&=\sqrt[\large 4]{\frac2{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}\right)}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't think the downvote was because I left the standard Gaussian integral for the OP, because there was no downvote for the same thing on fwgb's answer. However, if that is the case, I can uncomment the last two lines of my answer.